# How can I initiate vector of vectors with the same value in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

I understand that if I would like to initiate a vector with same values, I can simply do as below

```
vector<double> bcd= vector<double>(10,88);
```

which will generate a vector with 10 elements, each of them is equal to 88.

But how can I initiate a vector of vector with all elements is equal to 88? such as

```
vector< vector<double> > abc = vector< vector<double> >(???, ???);
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
std::vector< std::vector<double> > abc(10, std::vector<double>(10,88) );
```

This wastes one `std::vector<double>(10,88)` I believe.  And the copies may be less efficient than direct initializing the doubles with `88`.

```
template<class T, class...Args>
std::vector<T> generate_vector( std::size_t count, Args&&...args ) {
  std::vector<T> r;
  r.reserve(count);
  for (std::size_t i = 1; i < count; ++i)
    r.emplace_back(args...);
  if (count)
    r.emplace_back(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  return r;
}
```

then

```
auto abc = generate_vector<std::vector<double>>( 10, 10, 88 );
```

does it without any waste.